# How do "originalist" interpreters of the constitution cope with the 2nd amendment?

Tags: united-states, constitution, second-amendment

> A  well  regulated  Militia, being necessary to the security of a free State, the right  of  the  people  to  keep  and  bear  Arms,  shall  not  be infringed.

As far as I can see, from both the plain meaning of the words and the writings of the founding fathers, the 2nd was originally meant to apply to all weapons from a dagger to a cannon.

The *[Heller](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/07pdf/07-290.pdf)* decision (written by [Justice Scalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonin_Scalia)) seems to be the prime originalist interpretation of the 2nd Amendment. However that case was primarily about restrictions on handguns, not about "arms" in general. It is the wider meaning of "arms" that iterests me here.

*Heller* quotes the following definiton of "arms":

> Timothy  Cunningham’s  important  1771  legal  dictionary defined  “arms”  as  “any  thing  that  a  man  wears  for  his defence, or takes into his hands, or useth in wrath to cast at  or  strike  another.”

Given that a cannon is "used in wrath to strike at another" it certainly seems to fit the definition.

The other important term here is "bear arms". In the 18th century "bear" in this sense meant to carry, and this is the sense that *Heller* concentrates on. However the phrase "bear arms" more usually meant "[participate in organised military action](https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2018/06/07/what-does-it-mean-to-bear-arms)". Since organised military action at that time generally involved cannons it seems a big stretch to suppose that the framers intended to exclude cannons merely because they were too big for one man to carry. Also, at the time some cannons were in fact in private hands. In the [War of 1812](https://www.usni.org/magazines/navalhistory/2014-03/yes-privateers-mattered):

> As soon as word of the war arrived, ship owners in the port cities up and down the Atlantic coast raced to get their sleek sloops and schooners to sea in their new predatory role. They found cannon where they could, signed up oversized civilian crews, and sent messengers to Washington to get licenses called letters-of-marque from the federal government.

The Heller decision also rejects the idea that the 2nd Amendment only applies to firearms that were commonly available at the time it was written.

So a plain reading of the 2nd Amendment seems to imply that every American (plus non-citizens in the USA) has a constitutional right to keep and bear any military weapon of any kind, including but not limited to heavy machine guns, fighter and bomber aircraft, bazookas, surface-to-air missiles and tanks. The right to ammunition for all of these is also covered by the term "arms", as the framers could not possibly have envisaged gunpowder and bullets being banned while guns being protected.

As I said above, *Heller* is mostly about handguns, but it does make a minor reference to heavier weapons:

> Like   most   rights,   the   right   secured   by   the   Second   Amendment  is  not  unlimited.    From  Blackstone  through the  19th-century  cases,  commentators  and  courts  rou­tinely explained that the right was not a right to keep and carry  any  weapon  whatsoever  in  any  manner  whatsoever  and  for  whatever  purpose. [...] Although we do not undertake an exhaustive historical analysis today of the full scope of the Second  Amendment,  nothing  in  our  opinion  should  be  taken  to  cast  doubt  on  longstanding  prohibitions  on  the  possession  of  firearms  by  felons  and  the  mentally  ill,  or  laws forbidding the carrying of firearms in sensitive places such as schools and government buildings, or laws impos­ing conditions and qualifications on the commercial sale of arms

Here Scalia stops analysing the original meaning of the 2nd Amendment, and instead depends on the 1935 *[Miller](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/307/174/)* case. This seems very strange; not only is this a sudden departure from originalism, but the key holding of *Miller* was that

> Only weapons that have a reasonable relationship to the effectiveness of a well-regulated militia under the Second Amendment are free from government regulation.

However the rest of *Heller* overturns this, finding that the 2nd Amendment also includes a right to personal self defence, and hence that non-military weapons (such as small calibre handguns) are protected. (A cynical interpretation would be that Scalia wanted to overturn the ban on handguns but not the one on on heavy weapons, and then reasoned backwards from his desired conclusion. However such speculation is outside the scope of Politics.SE).

I know the principle that "dangerous" or "unusual" weapons can be banned, but [that makes no sense](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=744091026082099006084006000115089014121049062052064082095002067119070023011102069099043060010011039008118088084089030125066006062000008059031114106090013124027124050022031124080083101073017110026095097116070026024119096078029093116071122068125025118&EXT=pdf). All weapons are dangerous when pointed at you, and all new weapons are unusual when first invented. Also, if a weapon is banned then few people will have one, making this a circular definition.

One might reasonably construe "dangerous" as "having unpredictable effects", so for instance gas weapons and landmines could reasonably be considered unprotected. But any weapon used by the US military, with the possible exception of nukes, would fall outside this limitation.

Another attempt at restricting the 2nd is that arms are only protected for "lawful purposes". But again this fails the originalist test. The framers regarded the 2nd Amendment as safeguarding the right of "the militia", meaning all able-bodied men, to fight against invasion or tyranny. To this end they were also expected to practice using their weapons. So by an originalist reading of the 2nd Amendment, [firing a bazooka](https://www.facebook.com/nationalbazookaassociation/) at a firing range is a lawful and [therefore protected](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1980/12/14/machineguns-dont-kill/4b08bd82-6ea6-4c4b-9a2b-bd48a4d2b4ba/?utm_term=.e031016fc257) activity.

Of course one might argue that if bazooka practice is made unlawful then bazooka ownership lacks lawful purpose and hence is unprotected. However the same argument could equally be made against handguns and combat knives; the argument basically renders the entire 2nd Amendment meaningless so it cannot be what the framers meant.

So my questions are:

1. Does an originalist reading of the 2nd Amendment support the right of any citizen to keep and bear heavy military weapons?
2. If so, do originalist interpreters of the US Constitution  want to have a country where anyone can keep and bear heavy military weapons, or do they consider that the meaning of the 2nd should be understood in the context of modern technological civilization?
3. If the latter, then how do they distinguish their position from any other "[living constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Constitution)" theory?
4. Or is there a third option I am missing?

(Note: a shorter version of this question was posted on the [Volokh Conspiracy blog](https://reason.com/volokh/2019/01/30/apply-now-for-the-originalism-summer-sem#comment). It didn't get an answer there so I am posting it here.)

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest asking this on [Law.SE] instead.  It's not off-topic here, but I'm not sure we have the right set of expertise to answer it.  But you can give it a few days and see what happens.

Comment: I considered Law.SE as well, but as its about a particular (and rather political) interpretation of the constitution I thought it better here.

Comment: Valid points.  Certainly worth trying here, first.

Comment: This might be tricky to nail down, since, to my eyes and ears, "originalism"  usually seems to be or have been a posture/pretense of convenience and branding, more than an actual adherence to original intent of the Founders.

Comment: Side note: A false premise might be used in the cannon example:
'Given that a cannon is "used in wrath to strike at another" it certainly seems to fit the definition.'
Nothing about a cannon or any other weapon implies that it is being used in wrath rather than for defense and legitimate keeping or restoring of peace. Defense, including defense by offense, seems the most plausible use of 2nd Amendment rights.

Comment: In your quote about cannons, "letters of marque" refer to special exemptions given to civilians (usually ship captains) to hunt down criminals (usually pirates) and keep whatever they recovered. Presumably these captains securing cannons would have received special authorization to obtain those cannons from qualified dealers for the purposes of fighting for the USA in the war.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Originalism requires understanding of the original language, context, and intentions, which is explicitly indicated by the Founders as the only appropriate method for understanding the meaning of the Constitution. Therefore it becomes a matter of obtaining a correct understanding of intentions, which should come easily in many cases if we have got our own facts and intentions right.

Comment: @pygosceles - Thank you for the condescending statement of the obvious. My comment was more towards the "facts and intentions right," and how claims of "originality" are notoriously convenient, relative and circumstantial by those who often invoke it or claim to adhere to it.

Comment: @ThomasThomas No, letters of marque only authorised military action, not possession of arms. This example https://constitution.org/mil/lmr/1812amer1.htm mentions the number of canon as part of the ship description (along with name, owner, number of crew etc), which implies that the canon were already on board when the letter was issued. The authorisation part is only about targets and territorial scope and doesn't mention armament.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Sure, but is there any level of discernment we could impart to the conversation by identifying which aspects of a given interpretation are erroneous, and which are valid? Otherwise it seems like poisoning the well or merely criticizing the term itself. It's a valid term, it only needs to be understood correctly, hence the plea for greater specificity lest we abandon a useful endeavor.

Comment: @pygosceles - My comment was specifically in regard to loose and misuse of the term, and how it's losing it's meaning in political discussions. Everyone claims they are the "originality" and the other is the "relativist" or "revisionist." Talking about Scalia as an "originalist," to cite the most often claimed proponent, is laughable. Of course there is a level of discernment. One has to focus in on historians and what they can tell us about the discussions and language at the time, rather than pundits or those "historians" paid by think-tanks with an agenda.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I am not sure anyone can disentangle your definition of originalist from "revisionist". It seems to me that anyone trying to interpret a Constitutional principle and apply it to new circumstances might be accused of no longer being an originalist because of the arrival of new information. I believe that correctly stating and adhering to Constitutional principles would in many cases solve this problem, without being particular about circumstantial changes, because principles transcend peculiarities of implementation and circumstance.

Comment: @pygosceles - there's nothing complicated about what I'm talking about - it's the same criteria you put forward, but relying on historical experts to make sure we have the language and context correct. What I'm talking about is someone like Scalia making a basically partisan political assessment, claiming it's because "those words were not in the Constitution" when it suits him, and then making other determinations from whole cloth, also ignoring centuries of precedent, even his own.  Bush v Gore, Heller, Citizens United - all radical partisan rulings by the so-called "originalist."

Comment: Hence, my commentary that the label was often one of convenience rather than actual principle. I'm not questioning whether originalism is possible or arguing that it is not a legitimate standard, I'm pointing out that those who clamor the loudest about it are not particular adherents to the concept, usually, so if we do have a discussion, we have to avoid this modern talking-point context.

Comment: "relying on historical experts" - experts by whose standard? The Constitution has some friends and some enemies that sometimes follow a party divide, therefore partisanry or non-partisanry cannot be the determinant of what is Constitutional or not or originalist or not. The fact that an interpretation coincides with a modern conservative view, for instance, does not in any way contradict its Constitutionality according to a genuine originalism. So no, let's not steer clear of "talking points" as a category. Instead, let's analyze them for their merits as fairly and reasonably as we can.

Comment: @pygosceles - Experts by the consensus of peer historical experts. When historians publish papers they go through a similar objective peer review process. Ones who have works that generally hold up as factual and not especially partisan and revisionist would be the ones given the most weight. Things like what terms in language of the day meant, backed up by voluminous study of writings and correspondence from that time. People who look up and verify whether there is record of a particular person making a statement, vs someone who quotes someone who quotes someone who "heard it somewhere," etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97492/discussion-between-poloholeset-and-pygosceles).

Comment: Just for the record here, peer review is not objective. It's multi-subjective, which only crudely approximates objectivity when the individuals are reliable and differently biased. We could point to a mountain of peer-reviewed material that is highly partisan and factually incorrect because the herd of peers was thinned to the point of becoming an echo chamber or an inepto-garchy.

Comment: A quick point about the Miller decision: it found that short-barreled shotguns were not protected because they were not in common military use only because the lawyers were unaware that they were in fact quite common in WW1.

Comment: @Ryan_L True, but that doesn't change the logic of the decision and how it applies more generally.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Not exactly.  It would have changed the result of that decision completely.  The NFA would've been struck down.  I agree it wouldn't preclude some future law about weapons that really weren't militarily-relevant, but the Miller decision would've been different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. No, even originalists recognize that rights have some limits. Speech is limited in cases of inciting violence, acceptable arms are similarly limited.
2. This is a false dilemma, the second amendment can be reasonably limited without wholesale reinterpretation to a modernized definition. There is a massive pile of evidence that the founders understood that everything had exceptional cases that required limited rights to some degree, or some or form of handling exceptional cases.
3. The living constitution theory attempts to redefine the constitution using modern definitions and understandings, which is effectively a way to change the constitution. An originalist would recognize the existing process for changing the constitution and encourage using that process to write new understandings into the constitution rather than simply interpret things as differently as needed for desired outcomes. This allows for some level of consistency in how parts of the constitution or laws in general will be applied as a basis for ruling.

The important distinction is that originalists would hold that the burden of proof is required to ban private ownership of a specific weapon/class of weapon. Rather then proving that something is close enough to what existed in 1800 to be allowed for private ownership, according to a living constitution theory.

Comment: Two questions: 1. How can the blanket ban on heavy weapons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_II_weapons) be considered an "exceptional case"? 2. Does this mean that a ban on handguns would also be constitutional if there was evidence that it would be a good idea?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Can you be more specific about how that wikipedia page supports your argument? From reading it I find "The ownership of Title II weapons is not illegal" which doesn't sound like a "blanket ban" to me, and I also don't see anything in it which relates to originalist interpretations of the constitution.

Comment: @KamilDrakari OK "blanket ban" was hyperbolic, but in some states it is "no-certify" (i.e. blanket ban) and in many it is at the unlimited discretion of the local police, which for ordinary citizens probably means the same thing in practice: no senior policeman will put their career on the line by saying "yes" when they can just as easily say "no". The point is that the 2nd is basically a dead letter for anything heavier than a semi-automatic rifle.

Comment: @KamilDrakari "license" - The permission granted by  authority to exercise a certain "privilege". i.e. Not a right. i.e. The right to posses Title II weapons does not exist and is a privilege granted by the state to those it deems worthy.

Comment: I still don't see how the restrictions on Title II weapons can be "exceptional". However this looks like the best explanation of the originalist position I'm likely to get, so I've accepted it.

Comment: There is some false information here, leading to a false analogy: "Speech is limited in cases of inciting violence, acceptable arms are similarly limited". James Madison wrote that freedom of speech applies to "anything but false facts". Inciting to violence is not specified as unprotected speech--that would have undermined the legitimacy of the Declaration of Independence, which elicits armed revolution against tyrants. Therefore the analogy that "some kinds of arms" ought to be categorically banned or even that there exists a tacit loophole on the basis of "proof" is not supported.

Comment: One important concept to bear in mind is that of "prior restraint."  It is permissible to punish those who abuse their right of free speech to put others' lives in danger by shouting "fire" in a theater, for instance.  However it is not permissible to require all prospective theater goers to be fitted with gags to prevent it. Not even if you make "talk in the theater" licenses available to "persons of good character."  That would be exercising "prior restraint" over a fundamental right.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to **modify** the questions slightly [with explanation] so as to make a direct answer easier:

> Does an originalist reading of the 2nd Amendment support the right of
> any citizen [**in good standing**] to keep and bear heavy military weapons?

Absolutely. The rationale for the 2nd Amendment is "the security of a free state" and the [oath of citizenship](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/naturalization-test/naturalization-oath-allegiance-united-states-america), of military enlistment, and of office obligates us to protect worthy citizens from assault by "all enemies, foreign and domestic". By restricting what kinds of arms are allowed, we are infringing on the right and subverting its purposes. A heavy-weapons-armed enemy could make all citizens with only lighter arms into sitting ducks, contradicting the purposes of the Second Amendment.

> If so, do originalist interpreters of the US Constitution want to have
> a country where anyone can keep and bear heavy military weapons, or do
> they consider that the meaning of the 2nd should be understood in the
> context of modern technological civilization?

Qualifying "anyone" correctly*, the answer would be **yes** and **yes**. Nothing in the context of modern technological civilization contradicts the necessity of the security of a free state nor of the populace being **adequately** armed to ensure this security. A ban on heavy weapons is an admission that citizens are not actually allowed to ensure the security of a free state through bearing arms adequate to ensure that purpose, which contradicts the Constitution. This does not negate the necessity of a well-organized militia, but the Second Amendment itself and U.S. federal code makes clear that the [constituents](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/10/246) of that well-organized militia are the citizens themselves, therefore the people are the stewards of such arms as are necessary to accomplish its purpose. It is the ultimate separation of powers. I envision the military as being hierarchical; if our commander-in-chief were captured or if our federal governors were dissolved or destroyed, our Constitution would not prohibit but rather encourages the individual citizens to remain locally organized and fighting to the last man. The same argument applies to all state and local governments--the removal of a unit leader should not and does not render the fighting unit ineffectual, unorganized, or unauthorized. Consistent with constitutional ethic, the ultimate sovereignty comes from God, and is given to the individual, and families, then to larger societies by consent of the governed, not from centralized government. I feel I should make it very clear that this is not advocating anarchy, which is a very silly and absurd idea. Our strength comes from our unity. I am simply observing that the right and responsibility to defend one's family and country and to be locally organized and capable **does not break down** when the "higher" authorities are unreachable. Article I, Section 8,  10 and Section 10.3 in the Constitution corroborate this view:

> ... reserving to the States respectively, the Appointment of the Officers,
> and the Authority of training the Militia according to the discipline
> prescribed by Congress;
>
> No State shall, without the Consent of Congress, [...]
> engage in War, unless actually invaded, or in such imminent Danger as
> will not admit of delay.

*If "anyone" means any citizen who has not been convicted of any serious, violent crime or has otherwise had his personal right to bear arms revoked by due process and trial by an impartial jury, then **yes**, this is a non-negotiable, uninfringeable citizen right; there are no exceptions to it except as individually revoked by means of due process. Any measure that does not rely exclusively on due process to revoke or infringe any citizen's right is tyranny.

> If the latter, then how do they distinguish their position from any
> other "living constitution" theory?

The modern context does not necessitate rendering the purpose and intent of the 2nd Amendment ineffectual, as I have outlined above.

That military organization and direction are to be provided through the highest available authority and organized subordinately into state and local roles, and that the individual citizens reserve the right and autonomy for self-protection without limit, is evident from these sources.

Comment: The level of ridiculousness of "anarchy" depends on which definition of the word you're using. Translated into modern English the word would mean "no king" or "no ruler". The original sense of it is very much filled by the kind of "sovereignty comes from the bottom up" society you describe. It did not congeal into its own political movement until some time after America formed, and then the actions of various anarchist groups caused it to become conflated in the public mind with lawlessness and chaos. But you'll find a few scholars who refer to the founders as "proto-anarchists" and the like.

Comment: I've heard of some of the self-described anarchists you refer to. Certainly in the sense of not having a king, "anarchy" could be an applicable term to organization of the people of the United States. The Greek root word appears to bear the connotations of a chief, a leader, a commander, a ruler or a prince, depending on the etymology one consults. The organization of the militia and the universality of the right do indeed entail that whether it is the commander in chief, a local unit commander or an individual armed citizen, the American body is never leaderless, which might seem a paradox.

Comment: And the fellow who first used the term described it basically as a rejection of the idea that one man may have a moral right to rule over another.  This is, of course, a very dangerous idea to established rulers, which is probably why the idea that anarchy necessarily means no order and no law gets pushed so hard. In point of fact there have been several societies throughout history which could be described as anarchies. A common identifier to pick out the philosophy is "The king doesn't make the law, the law makes the king" and similar.

Answer (score 4):

> Does an originalist reading of the 2nd Amendment support the right of
>   any citizen to keep and bear heavy military weapons?

It should, if originalists were consistent. The 2nd Amendment's text is very clear, and there's no wiggle room. But then you have to allow felons and the mentally ill access to guns...

> If so, do originalist interpreters of the US Constitution want to have
>   a country where anyone can keep and bear heavy military weapons, or do
>   they consider that the meaning of the 2nd should be understood in the
>   context of modern technological civilization?

I have encountered several originalists who find the idea of Class 3 weapons to be completely against the constitution, so I think it safe to say that no, technology is irrelevant to the 2nd Amendment for them.

It is difficult to find one that will admit that owning something like C4 should be perfectly unregulated because they know how it sounds. Virtue signalling is real.

> If the latter, then how do they distinguish their position from any
>   other "living constitution" theory?

In my experience, the only difference between a living constitution scholar and an originalist scholar is which parts they feel are sacred. Even Justice Thomas has wavered from time to time, and he has written sympathetically of child abuse when the action was socially acceptable in 1787. Nobody wants to throw out 200+ years of case history and just read the text. The founders wouldn't have used common law if they had meant for that to happen anyway!

Comment: I've down voted this answer, because of the side handed comment "But then you have to allow felons and the mentally ill access to guns..."  It is Constitutionally sound for these individuals to be disenfranchised of Second Amendment protections for their rights, following the Due Process of Law. I'd downvote this a second time, because there are originalists that want to throw out 200+ years of case history, ranging from Barron V Baltimore, to Kelo V New London, not for getting Wickard v Filburn or the Slaughterhouse Cases.

Comment: @DrunkCynic What due process of the law is afforded the mentally ill?

Comment: Depends, choose your state: http://www.ncsl.org/research/civil-and-criminal-justice/possession-of-a-firearm-by-the-mentally-ill.aspx

Comment: @DrunkCynic Which other Constitutional rights may be taken away with "due process" and which part of the Constitution allows it, in an originalist reading?

Comment: All of them. See the 5th Amendment - "nor shall be compelled in any criminal case to be a witness against himself, nor be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law."

Comment: @DrunkCynic So you can have your 5th Amendment rights stripped after losing them at trial, in your view?

Comment: Point of interest:  "Felony" originally referred to capital crimes as a group.  That is, crimes for which the penalty was death. So a viable originalist way of dealing with such things would be to say that "anyone who can't be trusted with a weapon shouldn't be allowed to live here freely." Which...  Isn't a bad litmus test if you think about it since weapons are notoriously easy to come by in any modern society.

Answer (score -3):

> If so, do originalist interpreters of the US Constitution want to have a country where anyone can keep and bear heavy military weapons, or do they consider that the meaning of the 2nd should be understood in the context of modern technological civilization?

If we follow the definition on Wikipedia, they would consider the latter. The definition of originalism according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Originalism) (emphasis is mine):

> In the context of United States law, originalism is a concept regarding the interpretation of the Constitution that asserts that all statements in the constitution **must be interpreted based on the original understanding of the authors or the people at the time it was ratified.**

Comment: But 9mm semi-automatic pistols were also not available in the 18th century. By that argument only black-powder weapons are protected. Conversely, there were "military" weapons in the sense that they only had use in a military context (as opposed to individual hunting or self defence). Heller rejected this line of reasoning.

Comment: @PaulJohnson well, that's for the interpreters to decide. The originalists, according to the definition I provided, will try to argue why their view point corresponds to the original understanding of the authors of the amendment. As a non-American, I'd argue that a 9mm that can hold like 10 rounds would be understood whereas an ATGM wouldn't.

Comment: This puts me in mind of Justice Samuel Alito's "I think what Justice Scalia wants to know is what James Madison thought about video games". Having the Supreme Court solemnly attempt to consider the mental impact of a modern weapons system on the framers, were they transported to the modern day, is an amusing idea but not a useful one.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I never said it was useful, I merely base myself on the originalist idea you asked about. If it were up to me, I wouldn't base myself on laws that old without continuing to evaluate if they're still sensible. For what it's worth, originalists do subscribe to that too, through updating the constitution in accordance with [article 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Five_of_the_United_States_Constitution).

Comment: Originalism is not just what the constitution says, but how it was sold when an amendment was ratified.  This would include the Federalist Papers, the Anti-Federalist papers, personal coorespondence, and common meaning of language at the time.  There are numerous documents that are consistent with the understanding that an individual citizen had the right to purchase fire power consistent with military of the common time for any number of emergency circumstances.

Comment: @hszmv that seems to follow from the definition. The last paragraph of my answer is more of my (non-American) interpretation. Obviously, others, especially those who want military grade guns to be sold, may argue in a different direction.

Comment: @JJJ:  I suggest that you excise the last paragraph as history will surprise you as to what features were available.  Automatic Weapons in their earliest predate the Revolutionary War by some 60 or so years.

Comment: @PaulJohnson - sorry, you're wrong. I'm sure you have opinions of phasers in Star Trek and Death Star super-laser in Star Wars, and genetically engineered babies and AI drone warfare. Yet, presumably, the Founding Fathers were at least just as wise as yourself. So why do you deny them ability to understand things they were not tangibly familiar with?

Comment: @user4012 perhaps they thought future law makers would be just as wise and more capable to legislate for future stuff because their living in future times makes them more capable to contemplate the needs of their time?

Comment: @JJJ - nope. Constitution is about principles, not details

Comment: @user4012 is that why they added article 5 to allow amending the constitution?

Comment: @JJJ - yes and no. They didn't mean it to be like India constitution (check out all the appendixes to see what I mean)

Comment: @user4012 that would sure be something, seeing how the Indian constitution didn't exist back then. ;)

Comment: @user4012 - I don't think Paul is claiming they would be unable to grasp the issues, I think he's mocking the inherent conflict with claiming to be a strict "originalist" and then trying to project a speculative opinion about what a Founder would think about issues or situations that did not exist at their time. Generally, originalists are so when it suits their desire to not change with the times.... when they have some radically extreme notion they want to forward, themselves, that originalism becomes much less important to them.

Comment: This is a remarkably bad argument because there were clearly "military grade weapons" that were known to exist, like all forms of artillery which effectively operate with the same principles as modern day artillery and are much more dangerous than 9mm handguns or whatever it is you have in mind. They have never been considered legal for individual ownership because they're understood to be ordinance instead of arms

Comment: @Joe in that case it can be interpreted as the authors intended not to allow those weapons (as you and my answer both say). I'll remove the last part of my answer because it seems to cause confusion..

Answer (score -4):

There is an important legal distinction that is missing from your otherwise quite through analysis, which is the distinction between "arms" (which you correctly point out has been understood to be anything an individual can carry) and "ordinance", which is typically understood to be military equipment that cannot be operated by a single person, and typically describes things like artillery. Artillery was known to exist at the time of the constitution and was commonly understood to be "ordinance".

You use a cannon in your examples. A cannon does not qualify as "arms" because it requires a dedicated military unit to operate it (at least 2-4 men and probably also a horse to pull it).  For a more modern example, the machine gun is typically also thought of as ordinance, given that they usually require a crew to operate, which is why private ownership of machine guns is effectively banned in the United States regardless of the Second Amendment. I don't know of there has ever been a test case or law regarding the Bazooka or any other man-portable anti-tank rockets, but these are usually deployed by two or three man teams when used in the military, so I think they would probably be considered ordinance as well. Nuclear weapons are definitely ordinance and are also banned by several other laws that have withstood legal scrutiny without much controversy.

Comment: I think you need to cite evidence that the founders viewed "arms" as excluding all forms of ordinance.

Comment: @Paul Johnson You yourself cited in the question that the founders explicitly viewed arms as being for individual weapons, and that prior precedents have found that as well. What exactly is the additional evidence that you need?

Comment: I said *Given that a cannon is "used in wrath to strike at another" it certainly seems to fit the definition [of arms]*. Yes, "arms" can mean individual weapons, but there is no reason to think that it cannot also mean heavy ordinance too. Unless you have evidence otherwise. For example, did anyone talk about "arms and ordinance" to make it clear that they meant both?

Comment: Actually I think you have a bigger problem. "Ordnance" (note spelling) has two meanings. One is heavy weapons, as you say, but the other is military weapons and ammunition in general. The latter was the original meaning: the heavy weapons meaning emerged in the 15th century. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ordnance

Comment: https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_1301930  The one on the right is a privately-owned warship (hence "privateer") with 21 guns.  These would have probably been some combination of six and eight pound cannon given the size of the ship, possibly with some four-pounders in the bow and stern.  Depending on the owner's budget it may even have been equipped with explosive shells.  Although since most privateers were in it for the plunder they likely would only have used them to fend off a larger warship that they couldn't outrun. Cannon were expensive, but purchasable.

Comment: Incidentally, you can legally own a cannon, a fully operational tank, and a heavy machine gun in America. The approval process is long and expensive but does exist. IIRC, for explosives, it's *per device* so if you want a sack of grenades, it's a whole process and fee list per grenade. (Been a while since I looked all that up but I'm like....96% confident this is still correct.)